# Configure Meteor in a server without websocket support

Tags: linux, websocket, meteor

I was asked to test a meteor (js) website in a server without websockets support, how can I achieve this? How can I really know that a server is not capable of using websockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using environment variables. Remember to always do this on server, either by using `/server/lib` or `/lib/server` folder or `Meteor.isServer` flag. This will do the trick:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  process.env.DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS = 1;
});
```

You can read more about using environment variables with Meteor on [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables).

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, when websockets are disabled, Meteor uses sockjs which is a websockets emulator library.

More info here:

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Websockets

Answer (score -1):

This project might help folks who get here:
https://github.com/cult-of-coders/fusion